# What's up with the 5 minute limit on editing a comment?

Tags: feature-request, comments

It is discouraging to type all your work in the comment field, and then have it time out.  It legitimately took me that long because I was doing some research.

There's no timer or progress bar, so you don't know there's a limit until you're over it.

I understand the need for some sort of timeout, but could it please be a bit longer?  I imagine 5 minutes is difficult for disabled people who have trouble typing rapidly.

Answer (score 5):

If you really need more than 5 minutes to edit a comment, delete the comment and comment again. The limit is there to prevent people rewriting history, by altering a comment which has already been replied to or to which other action has been taken because of it. The 5 minute limit matches the grace period for post edits that don't cause a revision.

Comment: In fact, I used the workaround you suggest. And the text I had typed was still available to copy and paste. So it's not fatal if you think of that -- just annoying.